# r checking if row elements are within bounds

Tags: r, boundary

I am working with a large set of combinations. I would like a way to eliminate a portion of them, such that all combinations where the elements are close together (where close is set by me) are eliminated. (Note, it may take a second or two, it's rather large).

Let's make an example:

```
library(gtools)

support<-matrix(seq(0,1,by=0.1), ncol=1)
support.n<-as.matrix(permutations(length(support), 3,support))
```

But now I would like to eliminate all rows where any 2 combinations are "close" (say, within +/-0.2 of each other, inclusive). That is to say, how do I convert:

```
...
[964,]  1.0  0.7  0.0
[965,]  1.0  0.7  0.1
[966,]  1.0  0.7  0.2
[967,]  1.0  0.7  0.3
[968,]  1.0  0.7  0.4
[969,]  1.0  0.7  0.5
[970,]  1.0  0.7  0.6
[971,]  1.0  0.7  0.8
[972,]  1.0  0.7  0.9
[973,]  1.0  0.8  0.0
[974,]  1.0  0.8  0.1
[975,]  1.0  0.8  0.2
[976,]  1.0  0.8  0.3
[977,]  1.0  0.8  0.4
[978,]  1.0  0.8  0.5
[979,]  1.0  0.8  0.6
[980,]  1.0  0.8  0.7
[981,]  1.0  0.8  0.9
[982,]  1.0  0.9  0.0
[983,]  1.0  0.9  0.1
[984,]  1.0  0.9  0.2
[985,]  1.0  0.9  0.3
[986,]  1.0  0.9  0.4
[987,]  1.0  0.9  0.5
[988,]  1.0  0.9  0.6
[989,]  1.0  0.9  0.7
[990,]  1.0  0.9  0.8
```

into the much thinner:

```
....
[964,]  1.0  0.7  0.0
[965,]  1.0  0.7  0.1
[966,]  1.0  0.7  0.2
[967,]  1.0  0.7  0.3
[968,]  1.0  0.7  0.4
[969,]  1.0  0.7  0.5
```

where the row names are incorrect since I didn't calculate out what happens to them.
I have been looking at the commands any(x), and some various which() type commands but can't seem to get the magic to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you. `x` is an alias for each row of `support.n`, each pair combination is created from the row elements and the minimum absolute difference between each pair is checked against 0.2. It returns a `TRUE/FALSE` which is then used to subset support.n -

```
support.n[
  apply(
    support.n, 
    1, 
    function(x) 
      min(
        abs(
          diff(
            combn(
              x,
              2
              )
            )
          )
        )
    ) > 0.2,
  ]
```

Comment: After a time test, I have found that codoremifia's answer runs faster than Neal Fultz's answer by almost 25% (ten seconds) in a given application. I find this remarkable because it contains some extra commands and I assumed they would be slower. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

I think codoremifa and I are on the same page here. Our answers use the same logic and provide the same values for your sample data. Here's what I put together:

```
f <- function(x, threshold = .2) {
 combinations <- combn(length(x),2)
 keep <- all(abs(x[combinations[1,]] - x[combinations[2,]]) > threshold)
 return(keep)
}
```

Then `apply` function `f`, by row, to create an index of `TRUE/FALSE` values to select the appropriate rows of `support.n`:

```
a <- support.n[apply(support.n, 1,f),]
```

To confirm that our answers were the same, I saved codoremifa's answer as `b`:

```
> all.equal(a,b)
[1] TRUE
```

For large objects, either in terms of the # of rows or the # of columns, you could eliminate the overhead of calculating `combn()` for each row by doing that ahead of time and simply indexing it in each row. This example however runs in .05 seconds on my machine, so not worth making a more complicated function here.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is also very similiar, gives the same answer. I don't think the `combn()` stuff is really necessary, instead I would just sort each row instead and take the `diff` of that:

```
support.n[ apply(support.n, 1, function(x) all(diff(sort(x)) > .2) ) , ]
```